# how to run an $.ajax method on dialog ok button click

Tags: jquery, ajax, dialog

I want to delete a row from my html table on the click of corresponding delete button. What happens is that if i use a confirm box then everything goes fine but i dont want to use confirm box instead of that i want to use a dialog box with ok button and on the click of ok button it should perform the same function as it does with the confirm box. I am providing both the codes one with the confirm box and other with the dialog box .Help me do the same with that dialog box.
jquery code of confirm box which works fine-

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('input[type=button]').click(function()
    {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this row?"))
        {
            var ID = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
            var data = 'id=' + ID ;
            var parent = $(this).parent().parent();

            $.ajax(
            {
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "delete.php",
                   data: data,
                   cache: false,

                   success: function()
                   {
                    parent.fadeOut('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
                   }
             });
        }
    });


});
```

jquery code with dialog box -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#modal').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
     title: 'Delete Confirm Box',
     width: 400,
      buttons : [
            {
                text: 'OK',
                click: function () {
                    $("#modal").dialog('close');
                       del_row();
                       alert("done");        
                }
            },
            {
                text: 'Cancel',
                click: function () {
                    $("#modal").dialog('close');
                }
            }
        ]
});
$('input[type=button]').click(function(){
   $('#modal').dialog('open');
    });
 });
and the part which  i want to execute on ok click of dialog box-
$('input[type=button]').click(function()
{
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this row?"))
    {
        var ID = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
        var data = 'id=' + ID ;
        var parent = $(this).parent().parent();

        $.ajax(
        {
               type: "POST",
               url: "delete.php",
               data: data,
               cache: false,

               success: function()
               {
                parent.fadeOut('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
               }
         });
    }
});
```

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do you just need to copy the code in the `input[type=button]` click handler in to the `OK` button click handler of the dialog...?

Comment: yeah actually ..but while doing so "this" keyword refers to dialog box whereas that this refers to the input[type=button] and hence the change occurs in corresponding row .ie. the corresponding row is deleted .. i tried copying that code into ok button click handler but it fadesout entire page

Comment: how do i include input[type=button ]click's corresponding row ..so that the action can be performed on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create `ID` and `parent` as global variables and set it in `$('input[type=button]')` click function. In this way you can use `this`. After that, in the ok function of your modal, raise the ajax call:

```
var ID = 0;
var parent = null;

$('input[type=button]').click(function(){
   ID = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
   parent = $(this).parent().parent();
   $('#modal').dialog('open');
});

$('#modal').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    title: 'Delete Confirm Box',
    width: 400,
    buttons : [
        {
            text: 'OK',
            click: function () {
                $("#modal").dialog('close');

                var data = 'id=' + ID;
                $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "delete.php",
                    data: data,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function()
                    {
                        parent.fadeOut('slow', function(){
                            $(this).remove();
                        });
                    }
                });    
            }
        },
        {
            text: 'Cancel',
            click: function () {
                $("#modal").dialog('close');
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't like to introduce global variables into my code so I found a work around for this by using `addClass` jquery function. Just add a class to identify the html element to be removed in the code so that it can be filtered/searched from within inside the modal.

```
$('input[type=button]').click(function(){
   $(this).parent().parent().addClass("ToBeDeleted");
   $('#modal').dialog('open');
});

$('#modal').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    title: 'Delete Confirm Box',
    width: 400,
    buttons : [
        {
            text: 'OK',
            click: function () {
                $("#modal").dialog('close');

                var $parent = $(".ToBeDeleted");
                var ID = $parent.attr('id');
                var data = 'id=' + ID;
                $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "delete.php",
                    data: data,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function()
                    {
                        $parent.fadeOut('slow', function(){
                            $(this).remove();
                        });
                    }
                });    
            }
        },
        {
            text: 'Cancel',
            click: function () {
                $("#modal").dialog('close');
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

Now, since the element we added the class to `$(this).parent().parent()` is getting removed by the `remove()` function, we leave no trace of the class we added in our code. Hence it wont interfere in repeated execution of the code (say if you have multiple `input[type=button]` in your code.)